# NumPy Fast Way To Get Multiple Rows By Indexes

Tags: python, numpy

Given a multidimensional array of shape `(6, 100, 2)`, and a list of indexes (for example: `[1,2,3,1,5,0,0,0,1]`) and I would like to get a numpy ndarray with the data as in these indexes (meaning, the output shape is `(9, 100, 2)` and rows 6,7,8 are duplicates of each other).

The naive solution:

```py
arr = []
indexes = [1,2,3,1,5,0,0,0,1]
for i in indexes:
  arr.append(data[i])
arr = np.stack(arr)
```

This naive solution wastes a lot of time in `__getitem__` and the `stack` operation, and I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this with numpy?

Comment: You just use `a[b]` with `a` the array with shape `(6, 100, 2)`, and `b` the indexing array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use subscripting. So if `data` is your 6×100×2 matrix, and `indexes` is your list of indexes, you can retrieve the result with:

```
result = data[indexes]
```

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed faster, by around 1.7x. It still hangs a lot of time in the `__getitem__` but there probably ain't nothing to do about that.